# How to pass host component's CSS class to children?

Tags: css, angular

I cannot understand how to pass host component CSS class to a children element. I created a custom element:

```
...

const CUSTOM_INPUT_VALUE_PROVIDER: Provider = {
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => FormFieldComponent),
  multi: true,
}

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  providers: [CUSTOM_INPUT_VALUE_PROVIDER],
  selector: 'form-field',
  template: `
    <div>
      <input
        (change)="onChange($event.target.value)"
        (blur)="onTouched()"
        [disabled]="innerIsDisabled"
        type="text"
        [value]="innerValue" />
    </div>
  `
})
export class FormFieldComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input() innerValue: string;

  innerIsDisabled: boolean = false;

  onChange = (_) => {};
  onTouched = () => {};

  writeValue(value: any) {
    if (value !== this.innerValue) {
      this.value = value;
    }
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void { this.onChange = fn; }
  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void { this.onTouched = fn; }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean) {
    this.innerIsDisabled = isDisabled;
  }

  get value(): any {
    return this.innerValue;
  }

  set value(value: any) {
    if (value !== this.innerValue) {
      this.innerValue = value;
      this.onChange(value);
    }
  }
}
```

And then use it like this in some reactive form:

```
<form-field formControlName="title"></form-field>
```

**Problem:** I added some validation in `FormBuilder` to `title` form control and when it not pass validation, Angular add classic css classes to `form-field` element: `ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched`.

How i can pass this CSS classes from host element to my input element in `form-field` component?

---

It is not duplicate of [Angular 2 styling not applying to Child Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38798002/angular-2-styling-not-applying-to-child-component). Changing `Encapsulation` does not resolve the problem.

Comment: Ok, I re-read the question. Is this a real example? Why do you want to do this instead of just using `<input>` elements where you use `<form-field>`? It seems to add needless complexity, especially as you have a reactive form already.

Comment: @msanford, yes exactly. I think that this variant is more modular, you can use `form-field` instead of `input` and everywhere will be same style and logic

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a way to do what you want by just knowing the angular classes of the hosting elements and not necessarily passing them down.

If so, your work-around would look something like this in the css of the custom form element:

```
:host.(ng-class)>>>HTMLelement {
  property: value
}
```

Example:

```
:host.ng-valid>>>div {
  border-left: 5px solid #42a948;
}
```

- The ":host" part of this allows us to use the hosting (parent) html elements
- The ">>>" is the deep selector that allows us to apply these styles to all children matching selection property (in this case, we're looking for div elements)